# activator dist command does not finish on opsworks instances

Tags: playframework, chef-infra, cookbook, recipe, aws-opsworks

I'm having a weird problem with opsworks here.

I got a script like below.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/ubuntu/download/xxxxsite
mkdir ranranran
activator dist
mkdir endendend
cp target/universal/xxxxsite-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip /home/ubuntu/deployment/ 
cd /home/ubuntu/deployment && unzip xxxxsite-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip 
nohup ./xxxxsite-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/xxxxsite &
```

And it's definitely loaded and executed by the recipt like below.

```
    script_name = "deploy" + pname + ".sh"
    log " --- START to run script " + script_name + " --- "
    cookbook_file "/home/ubuntu/deploy_dist" do
      source "#{script_name}"
      mode 0755
    end

    execute "run_deploy" do
      user "root"
      cwd "/home/ubuntu"
      command "./deploy_dist"
    end
```

The thing is that I got both ranranran and endendend directories but the "activator dist" didn't finish at all. It was supposed to produce a zip package but eventually got nothing. I tried both Deploy and Execute recipe with opsworks. However, it just was reported as success. So I couldn't even have a clue to check what's going on. In short, this problem is that everything worked well excluding "activator dist".

Please anybody can help explain why. Appreciate your help!

NOTE: activator dist here should download a list of dependences first and then build a zip

Comment: And we're supposed to guess if `activator` code is a shell script, a binary, if it's forking to work in background or not ? (Not related to chef IMHO as you're saying it works as expected creating the script and running it)

Comment: It took me some time to repeatedly test this and eventually I had some result. I'm still not certain about if it was a bug or just a drawback because I'm certainly not a chef expert. However, I fixed it by moving the "activator dist" part to be a part of chef recipe, instead of staying in the script to run. So it looked like the script resource had some weird parallel mechanism to run commands in a script.